# Spring Boot 1.4 custom bootstrapper

Tags: spring-boot, classloader

I have a project which uses a custom bootstrapper to startup a spring boot application. The bootstrapper is used to provide a built in update mechanism. Therefore the spring boot application is stored in a predefined folder. In case of an update the new version will be stored in the same directory. With the next application start the bootstrapper will then start the latest version based on the version number of the files.

Now I want to update the Spring Boot application to the latest Spring Boot version 1.4.0. With this the application is not starting anymore when using the custom bootstrapper as it cannot find the included SSL certificate (packaged in the spring boot application). When starting the application without the custom bootstrapper everything is working fine.

I guess it has something to do with the classloader as the path to the included certificate is wrong (! after classes):

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry BOOT-INF/classes!/default-server-ssl.p12 not found in
```

The relevant part of the bootstrapper is the following:

```
initializeEnvironment();
ensureTempDirExists();

//get the latest application version
File agentApplicationFile = applicationVersionLookup.getLatestVersion();
URL agentFileUrl = agentApplicationFile.toURI().toURL();

//add spring boot application to classpath and run spring boot application
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{agentFileUrl}, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass("org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher");
 Method main = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
 main.invoke(null, new Object[]{new String[0]});
```

With Spring Boot 1.3.6 this worked very well. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: So far my solution is to extract the archive into a temporary folder and add the relevant folders to the classpath. This basically works but is not my preferred solution as the bootstrapper depends on the archive format of spring boot. If this changes again (as for 1.4 release) the bootstrapper will not work without modification